# New Contribution

Tags: contributions, financial-types

After I add a new contribution, and select a Finance Type for it, when I view it, the Financial Type shows a different one under **"Contribution Amount"** section while it displays correctly at the top of the page.  I found out that the financial Type for all of my latest gifs is being set to "4" in the table **"civicrm_financial_item"**.  why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add a bit more info: Are you using Line Items? Are you also selecting Price Set?